# Emit particles from the volume of a custom mesh in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, particles

So I’ve got custom mesh shapes and I’m emitting particles but I can’t get to emit them from inside the volume, only vertices and triangles, what’s the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that if you are using the old particle system nor the shader effect graph.

What you could do is to duplicate your particle system and use a simple shape emission (sphere or whatever) to match your custom mesh.

That way, you'll emit particle from the surface of your custom mesh and from the inside, even if it doesn't perfectly match your custom mesh